# How to get product details in Magento Go CMS page?

Tags: magento, magento-go

I want to display particular product details in Magento Go CMS page.

Normally in Magento, we can do it by inserting block by `{{block type="catalog/product" ..}}` with particular template - but in Magento Go where will the template file be?

How can I do that?

Comment: Because you don't have access to files on Magento Go, how could you upload your custom template?

Comment: Maybe you can use widgets for this. First make a widget which selects product and later include that widget in CMS page